# Excel Bar Graph width

Tags: excel, bar-chart, stacked-chart, stackedbarseries

I've data ranges (not excel table, just data ranges) mapped from different links having keys on rows and monthly value on columns,

| Column | M1 | M2 | M3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Key1 | 11 | 21 | 31 |
| Key2 | 12 | 22 | 32 |
| Key3 | 13 | 23 | 33 |

and I'm tryin to create a 100% stacked bar chart showing monthly trend, but whenever I try to crate the graph, it revert to bar chart with no width and overlapping on each other, so i can not understand whats wrong, could any one help

attached Error graph and expected graph (both have equal series overlap (100%) and gap width(70%)

[Error Graph vs Expected Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wo6y3.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in excel to use stacked bar graph.

Check here:https://www.educba.com/stacked-bar-chart-in-excel/

*I hope you are selecting the entire range.*

Comment: Thanks Rajat, 
can you specify which options specifically as both the charts shown have same properties! 
and yes, i'm selecting entire range